# Bigquery - rows between clause?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Haven't come up with a solution using Bigquery to this: say I have a table (call it TripSpeed) like this:

```
DeviceId | TripId | Speed | DateTime 
  5           1      0                 
  5           1      8                 
  5           1      12                
  5           1       0                               
  5           1       2                
  5           2       ..................
  5           2       .................
  6           ..........................
```

I want to re-org (aggragate) it into segments like :

```
DeviceId | TripId | Speed | DateTime
  5           1      0,8,12             
  5           1      0,2                        
  5           2       ....................
  5           2       ...................
  6           ............................
```

More notes:

1. group data by DeviceId and TripId
2. DateTime is unique for each row and precise to millisecond,and data need to be ordered by datetime within each group
3. Within a same group, row with speed=0 is the starter for each segment
4. I've already done other cleanings so that there will be no consecutive zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a group and then aggregation.  The assignment is pretty easy.  It is the cumulative sum of values that are zero.  The rest is aggregation.  BUT, this assumes that you have a column to specify the ordering of the rows.  I assume that is `datetime`:

```
select deviceid, tripid,
       group_concat(speed)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when speed = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by deviceid, tripid order by datetime) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by deviceid, tripid, grp
```

Answer (score 1):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH TripSpeed AS (
  SELECT 5 AS DeviceId, 1 AS TripId, 0 AS Speed, 1 AS DateTime UNION ALL                 
  SELECT 5, 1, 8, 2 UNION ALL                 
  SELECT 5, 1, 12, 3 UNION ALL                
  SELECT 5, 1, 0, 4 UNION ALL                               
  SELECT 5, 1, 2, 5 UNION ALL                
  SELECT 5, 2, 0, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 2, 1, 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 3, 0, 8 
)
SELECT DeviceId, TripId, STRING_AGG(CAST(Speed AS STRING)) AS Speed, Segment
FROM (
  SELECT DeviceId, TripId, Speed,
    COUNTIF(Speed = 0) OVER (PARTITION BY DeviceId, TripId ORDER BY DateTime) AS Segment
  FROM TripSpeed 
) 
GROUP BY DeviceId, TripId, Segment
-- ORDER BY DeviceId, TripId, Segment
```

Yet another version without analytic function but rather with string processing
Somehow I feel it can be cheaper  than above version

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT DeviceId, TripId, Speed
FROM (
  SELECT DeviceId, TripId, 
    STRING_AGG(
      CONCAT(IF(Speed = 0, '|', ','), CAST(Speed AS STRING)), 
      '' ORDER BY DateTime) AS Speed
  FROM TripSpeed 
  GROUP BY DeviceId, TripId
), UNNEST(SPLIT(Speed, '|'))  AS Speed
WHERE Speed <> ''
-- ORDER BY DeviceId, TripId
```

You can test it with the same dummy sample data

```sql
WITH TripSpeed AS (
  SELECT 5 AS DeviceId, 1 AS TripId, 0 AS Speed, 1 AS DateTime UNION ALL                 
  SELECT 5, 1, 8, 2 UNION ALL                 
  SELECT 5, 1, 12, 3 UNION ALL                
  SELECT 5, 1, 0, 4 UNION ALL                               
  SELECT 5, 1, 2, 5 UNION ALL                
  SELECT 5, 2, 0, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 2, 1, 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 3, 0, 8 
)
```

Comment: They both work. I'm little bit fussy on the semantics of cross product of a table and array...  seems hard to add more columns in as speed.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I accept @GordonLinoff answer just because it went before yours and is a working one too:)

Comment: Sure, understood and no problem. And ... sure, they both work :o) i know - dealing with "advanced" features can be more complex - but if you invest a little time to get nail it  - it gives you the whole new scope of power :o) feel free to experiment and ask questions - we are here to help you to learn